# Getting tree command to not display directories

Tags: shell, zsh, tree

I've read through the man pages for `tree` but I don't know if it is possible to have tree list only the filenames for all files that appear in any recursive search of a directory.

The closest I have gotten is: `tree -i --noreport dir/` which might give me something like:

```
./lib
order
crossCount.js
rank
acyclic.js
```

Where `order`, `lib`, and `rank` are directories that I do not want listed.

Comment: What's the point of using `tree` if you don't want to see the directories? `tree` shows a hierarchical view of files and directories, if you remove the directories it cannot show a hierarchy and becomes useless. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `tree` normally needs to print the directory name to get the tree-like structure.

How about using `find` instead?

```
find dir/ -type f
```

with above command you can get all and only files (`-type f`) recursively. It displays with path of the file, though.

In case that you don't want to display the path of the file, you can apply `basename` command at the end, like this:

```
find dir/ -type f -exec basename {} \;
```